# Sip Soft-Phone for BlackBerry - Is there any free application / source code available?

Tags: blackberry, sip

Is there any free application / source code available ?

Answer (score 1):

See [Is it possible to use MJSIP api with Blackberry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628849/is-it-possible-to-use-mjsip-api-with-blackberry)