# Is it possible to use MJSIP api with Blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, voip, sip

I am trying to develop an VOIP application for blackberry,after a long surf i came
to know about mjsip api.But i have a doubt that is it possible to use this api 
with blackberry development to create VOIP application.Please anyone knows the answer
help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, it's a nice project you found there! There is an J2ME version [MjSipME](http://www.mjsip.org/mjsipME.html), and the only thing I can say now for sure is that it compiles with Blackberry without any errors.

**UPDATE** You right, there are missunderstanding with packages/folders structure.

Steps to compile:

1. download [mjsip2me_1.6.zip](http://www.mjsip.org/download/mjsip2me_1.6.zip)
2. create blackberry project (I've used components 4.6)
3. in project src folder create such structure:
   [alt text http://img691.imageshack.us/img691/9311/structure.jpg](http://img691.imageshack.us/img691/9311/structure.jpg)
4. extract mjsip2me_1.6.zip, copy files and folders:

   - from mjsip2me_1.6\src\org\zoolu\ to project\src\org\zoolu\
   - from mjsip2me_1.6\src\j2me\local\ to project\src\local
   - from mjsip2me_1.6\src\j2me\microtools\ to project\src\org\zoolu\microtools
   - from mjsip2me_1.6\src\j2me\net\ to project\src\org\zoolu\net
   - copy mjsip2me_1.6\src\j2me\ExceptionPrinter.java into project\src\org\zoolu\tools
   - copy mjsip2me_1.6\src\j2me\RotatingLog.java into project\src\org\zoolu\tools
5. refresh your project, clean and build

It's j2me midlet so don't expect it will start on bb device, but at least it compiles.

Comment: Thanks for your Reply.I tried many times to import this library into Blackberry,but some packages are showing some errors.I dont know how to make this package to work with  blackberry application.Please can you provide some steps to do this.

Comment: Thanks Coldice the application compiled without any error.But the application is not the VOIP application,it is simple application to display the text.Did you tried any application to do VOIP in Blackberry.If you tried please provide the code also.Because i surfed a lot in the web but i didn't get any code for this.Please help me.

Comment: Well, as I understand you're talking about implementation sample. But if you look into org.zoolu.sip.message, you will see _public Message(byte[] buff, int offset, int len)_ method. I think SIP message by itself may be a carrier for any kind of media - text, video, audio. Just try to send recorded audio buffer, hope this will help.

Comment: And no, I don;t know any alternatives, although they may be :)